# Laravel5 dependency injection on Model

Tags: laravel-5, ioc-container

I have an Eloquent Model called Surface which is dependent on a ZipCodeRepository object:

```
class Surface extends Model{
    public function __construct(ZipCodeRepositoryInterface $zipCode){...}
```

and an Address object that hasMany surfaces.

```
class Address extends Model{
    public surfaces() { return $this->hasMany('App/Surface'); }
}
```

My issue is when I call `$address->surfaces` I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Surface::__construct() must be an instance of App\Repositories\ZipCodeRepositoryInterface, none given
```

I thought the IoC would automatically inject that.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338161/cant-pass-class-instance-to-constructor/22338753 ... especially the issue opened at github

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Thanks to @svmm for referencing [the question mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338161/cant-pass-class-instance-to-constructor/22338753). I found that you cannot use dependency injection on Models because you would have to change the signature on the constructor which doesn't work with the Eloquent framework.

What I did as an intermediate step, while refactoring the code, is use `App::make` in the constructor to create the object, such as:

```
class Surface extends Model{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->zipCode = App::make('App\Repositories\ZipCodeRepositoryInterface');
    }
```

That way the IoC will still grab the implemented repository. I am only doing this until I can pull the functions into the repository to remove the dependency.

Comment: Thank you!  When passing in a dependency to the Model constructor, I was getting a 'too few arguments' error when performing an Eloquent find(id) .  This method works much better

Comment: Thank you, after 1h of searching for a solution, this was the way to solve it.

Answer (score 9):

In Laravel 5.7 you can use the global `resolve(...)` method. I don't think the global `App` is defined in more recent version of Laravel.

```
$myService = resolve(ServiceName::class);
```

[Resolving in Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#resolving)

Answer (score 2):

However it might not be a good practice to inject services into your models either by constructor or method injection, think about designing the system in such a way that you do not need to do that and instead maybe inject the model into a service.

Let's see an example(just a dummy example in order to get to the point!).

- Say we have Basket and Order models, and we want to add orders to basket
- And we have a discount service that calculates discount based on orders
- Every time user adds an order to basket we need to calculate new discount and set it on basket

one approach is:

```
class OrderController
{
    function store(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        $basket = $user->getBasket();
        $basket->addOrder($order);
    }
}

class Basket
{
    private $discountService;

    public function __construct(DiscountService $discountService)
    {
        $this->discountService = $discountService;
    }

    function addOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $this->orders[] = $order;
        $discount = $this->discountService->calculateFor($this->orders);
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
}

class DiscountService
{
    function calculateFor(array $orders) {
        // code for calculating discount;
        return $discount;
    }
}
```

In this approach we injected discount service into Basket model

Another better approach would be like this:

```
class OrderController
{
    private $discountService;

    public function __construct(DiscountService $discountService)
    {
        $this->discountService = $discountService;
    }

    function store(User $user, Order $order)
    {
        $basket = $user->getBasket();
        $basket->addOrder($order);
        $this->discountService->setDiscount($basket);
    }
}

class Basket
{
    function addOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $this->orders[] = $order;
    }

    function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    function setDiscount(int $discount)
    {
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
}

class DiscountService
{
    function setDiscount(Basket $basket) {
        $discount = $this->calculateFor($basket->getOrders());
        $basket->setDiscount($discount);
    }

    private function calculateFor(array $orders)
    {
        // code for calculating discount
        return $discount;
    }
}
```

- In the first approach basket is making the decision about having discount, but this is not basket's concern
- In the first approach basket depends on discount service, but in real world you don't need a discount service to have a basket

Comment: This answer also showed me how the need of mocking can reveal code smells.