# dependency injection on model is not working

Tags: laravel

I am going to write a dependency injection in the model.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Conference_list extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $request;

    public function __construct( Request $request ){
        $this->request = $request;
    }
}
```

However, the following error occurred.

`Too few arguments to function App\\Models\\Conference_list::__construct()`

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.
Dependency injection is not available in the model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel5 dependency injection on Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636880/laravel5-dependency-injection-on-model)

Comment: @cbaconnier You can not use dependency injection on Model?

Comment: Nope: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3862 but as the link's answer says, you can still resolve manually if you really need to.

Comment: @cbaconnier The link you gave me and my problem, the content of the error is different. And if dependency injection is available on model, please give us specific examples.

Comment: As I said, **nope** which mean **no**, but you can still resolve it **manually** (see **answers** on both links and @george-hanson answer). Error is different because the model as been called in a different way, but the error is not related with the fact that you can't use DI in a model, which is well explained on both links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent Models already have a constructor. I wouldn't recommend overwriting this to add custom functionality.

Depending on what you are trying to do, there is likely to be a better way of doing it. It could be as simple as having a method on the model to set the request. This could be something such as:

```php
public function setRequest()
{
    $this->request = request();

    return $this;
}
```

That will allow you to either set the request manually by passing it an instance, or Laravel will resolve it from its Container automatically.

In your controller or wherever, you could then do something like:

```php
$model = (new App\Models\Conference_list())->setRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, if you **really** need to use Dependency Injection in a model without touching the `__construct`method

You can use a **trait** that will resolve it for your model

```
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
trait InjectRequest
{
    public static $request;

    protected static function bootInjectRequest()
    {
        self::$request = app(Request::class);
    }

    public function request(): Request
    {
        return self::$request;
    }
}
```

On your model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Traits\InjectRequest;

class Conference_list extends Model
{
    use InjectRequest;
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Call your model:

```
$request = (new App\Models\Conference_list())->request();
```

Find our more about bootable traits: https://www.archybold.com/blog/post/booting-eloquent-model-traits

Comment: I posted twice. Sorry for that